# (Mobile queries) "Display: inline" doesn't work

Tags: css

I have some text on my site that I want to be visible on mobile phones but not on computers. I tried with "display: none" in my CSS file and "Display: block" in my mobile queries, but it doesn't work for some reason (not even if I use !important). It do, however, work if I use the visible property, but I don't want to use that.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5y2vsmtz/2/

Or you can see the text here:

HTML:

```
<div class="mobiltext1">
        <div>Heading 1e<br></div>
        Description 1<br>
        <div>Heading 2<br></div>  
        Description 2<br> 
        <div>Heading 3<br></div>
        Description 3<br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px){
   .mobiltext1 {display:block; padding-top:30%;}
}

.mobiltext1 {
    display: none;
    font-family: Raleway Bold, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: rgba(80,80,80,0.99);
    }
```

Comment: `display:block` should work in mobile browsers too. Maybe you have other codes not visible to us causing this problem

Comment: `max-width: 380px` seems very narrow. Try increasing it.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the script above because the "visible" property works fine. However, I don't want to use this since Google maybe may see it as a try to manipulate ranking (i.e. spam). I increased the width and it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the max-width will allow it to work for more mobile devices.
Placing the @media css below the normal css causes it to override the former.

```
    .mobiltext1 {
        display: none;
        font-family: Raleway Bold, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5%;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: rgba(80,80,80,0.99);
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
.mobiltext1 {display:block; padding-top:30%;background-color:red}
}
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcoyc4ay/

Comment: what mobile device are you using?